# SASS SyntaxError when including web font

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

When I try to use `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` it throws this error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...awesome-webfont": expected ")", was ".woff);"
```

This is my `style.css` file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    src:font-image-url(fontawesome-webfont.woff);
}
```

If I comment the line `src:font-image-url(fontawesome-webfont.woff);`  this error appears

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...:image-url(ban2": expected ")", was ".jpg);"
```

I am using `gem "font-awesome-rails"` with rails 4.2.4 .

Comment: Is your GEM listed environment specific in your Gemfile? Something like `gem font-awesome-rails, :group => 'development'`

Comment: Did you follow the [usage](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#usage) instructions?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @Navin I have updated my comment

Comment: @abhi No not like that

Comment: @vucko yes I followed the same things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to wrap your URL in quotation marks.

Secondly, SASS does not have a [URL helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/) `font-image-url`. You're maybe looking for `font-url`, which does the following:

> Generates a path to an asset found relative to the project's font directory.

Applying the above, you should have something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
}
```

The second error seems to come from not wrapping a URL value in quotation marks a well.

Comment: rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development is working fine , I have modified the style.css file as per your answer also but it says rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @drenmi thumbs up for last line.